# Generating the power set of a String

Tags: java, recursion

So I'm trying to create a method that generates the power set of a given string. So far, I've come up with this which incorrectly outputs "[abc, bc, c, b, ac, c, a, ab, b, a]".

```
public static ArrayList<String> powerSet(String s){
        ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(!s.isEmpty())
        set.add(s);

        for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){
            String substring = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1);
            set.addAll(powerSet(substring));
        }


        return set;
     }
```

This is for part of a homework assignment, and I'm not allowed to create any sort of helper class, and the method must be of type ArrayList. The method must involve recursion.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What should the answer be? Does the order matter?

Comment: @PaulBoddington The order does not matter, but the correct answer should be something along the lines of "", "a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc".

Comment: Ok, well you've essentially done it. Just add "", use HashSet rather than ArrayList, then convert to an ArrayList at the end.

Comment: @PaulBoddington The main problem with my solution is that it prints duplicates. Would using HashSet fix this? I'm not familiar with it which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, a HashSet would fix this. A Set is a Collection that does not allow duplicates.

Comment: Awesome! thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

i usually help my friends to find their own solution...
but this time i'll just give you the code... please read it!! don't copy!!

```
public static ArrayList<String> powerSet(String s){
    ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(s.isEmpty()){
        ans.add("");
        return ans;
    }

    ArrayList<String> withFirstElem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> withoutFirstElem = new ArrayList<String>();

    withoutFirstElem = powerSet(s.substring(1));

    for(String i : withoutFirstElem){
        withFirstElem.add(i+s.charAt(0)); // adding first elem
    }
    ans.addAll(withFirstElem);
    ans.addAll(withoutFirstElem);

    return ans;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "abc";

for (int i = 1; i <(int) Math.pow(2,input.length()) ; i++) {

    String eleman = "";
    int arrayindex = 0;

    for (int k = input.length() -1; k >= 0; k--) {

        String index = ((i >> k) & 1) == 1 ? "1" : "0";

        if(index == "1"){
            eleman += input.charAt(arrayindex); 
        }
             arrayindex++;
        }

        System.out.println(eleman);
    }
```

and answer

```
c
b
bc
a
ac
ab
abc
```

Comment: and if the string is "abcd" ?