# Find possible subsequences in java

Tags: java

Given a string S, find all the possible subsequences of the String in lexicographically-sorted order. I implemented in java but I am getting incorrect output. Please help

```java
class Solution
{
    public void helpr(String s,int ind,int n,StringBuilder curr,List<String> res){
        if(ind==n){
            res.add(curr.toString());
            return;
        }
        helpr(s,ind+1,n,curr.append(s.charAt(ind)),res);
        helpr(s,ind+1,n,curr,res);
    }

    public List<String> AllPossibleStrings(String s)
    {
        StringBuilder curr = new StringBuilder("");
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        helpr(s,0,s.length(),curr,res);
        Collections.sort(res);
        res.remove(0);
        return res;
    }
}
```

for input - `abc`
actual op: `abc abcc abcc abccbc abccbc abccbcc abccbcc`
required op: `a ab abc ac b bc c`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating the power set of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296514/generating-the-power-set-of-a-string) (in Java)

Comment: You never remove anything from the string builder so it gets bigger and bigger. You can start with that.

Comment: @Dici Thanks. I messed up with the concepts a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class SubSequences {
static void get_sequence(String str, String ans, int i) {
    // Base condition
    if (i == str.length()) {
        System.out.println("'" + ans + "'");
        return;
    }
    // Before character gets added to final
    get_sequence(str, ans, i + 1);
    // after character gets added to ans
    get_sequence(str, ans + str.charAt(i), i + 1);

}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    str = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("All possible subsequences are:");
    get_sequence(str, "", 0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Changed StringBuilder to String and its working now.

```
class Solution
{
    public void helpr(String s,int ind,int n,String curr,List<String> res){
        if(ind==n){
            
            res.add(curr);
            return;
        }
        
        helpr(s,ind+1,n,curr+s.charAt(ind),res);
        
        helpr(s,ind+1,n,curr,res);
    }
    public List<String> AllPossibleStrings(String s)
    {
        String curr ="" ;
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        helpr(s,0,s.length(),curr,res);
        
        Collections.sort(res);
        res.remove(0);
        return res;
    }
}
```